# Python string conversion, take out spaces, add hyphens

Tags: python, string, pandas, formatting, uuid

I have a column in a pandas data frame that is formatted like

> f1 d3 a4 0a d0 6a 4b 4a 83 d4 4f c9 1f 15 11 17

and I want to convert it to look like:

> f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117

I know I can use `replace(" ", "")` to take the whitespace out, but I am not sure how to insert the hyphens in the exact spots that I need them.

I am also not sure how to apply it to a pandas series object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that a single cell or the entire column? Also what is the logic behind the hyphens?

Comment: The entire column, The logic for the hyphens is that was the original format before it was downloaded from AWS athena, and now I need to join this dataframe to the original data(which has the hyphens)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a UUID, so I'd just use that module

```
>>> import uuid
>>> s = 'f1 d3 a4 0a d0 6a 4b 4a 83 d4 4f c9 1f 15 11 17'
>>> uuid.UUID(''.join(s.split()))
UUID('f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117')
>>> str(uuid.UUID(''.join(s.split())))
'f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117'
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['f1 d3 a4 0a d0 6a 4b 4a 83 d4 4f c9 1f 15 11 17',
                          'f1 d3 a4 0a d0 6a 4b 4a 83 d4 4f c9 1f 15 11 17']})

df['col'] = df['col'].str.split().str.join('').apply(uuid.UUID)
print (df)
                                    col
0  f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117
1  f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117
```

Comment: This is definitely something I did not know of before! I am still having trouble using it on a Pandas series though....  Using: "df.col = str(uuid.UUID(''.join(df.col.str.split()))) "  I get a type error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"

Comment: You would have to use `apply` or `str.replace`.  `df.col.str.split()` would give you a `Series` of `list`s.

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = "f1 d3 a4 0a d0 6a 4b 4a 83 d4 4f c9 1f 15 11 17"
c = "f1d3a40a-d06a-4b4a-83d4-4fc91f151117"
b = [4,2,2,2,6]

def space_2_hyphens(s, num_list,hyphens = "-"):
    sarr = s.split(" ")
    if len(sarr) != sum(num_list):
        raise Exception("str split num must equals sum(num_list)")
    out = []
    k = 0
    for n in num_list:
        out.append("".join(sarr[k:k + n]))
        k += n
    return hyphens.join(out)


print(a)
print(space_2_hyphens(a,b))
print(c)
```